# Regex that extract string of length that is encoded in string

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have the following string to parse:

```
X4IitemX6Nabc123
```

that is structured as follows:

- X... marker for 'field identifier'
- 4... length of item (name), will change according to length of item name
- I... identifier for item name, must not be extracted, fixed
- item...  value that should be extraced as "name"
- X... marker for 'field identifier'
- 6... length of item (name), will change according to length of item name
- N... identifier for item number, must not be extracted, fixed
- abc123... value that should be extraced as "num"
  Only these two values will be contained in the string, the sequence is also always the same (name, nmuber).

What I have so far is

```
\AX(?I<namelen>\d+)U(?<name>.+)X(?<numlen>\d+)N(?<num>.+)$
```

But that does not take into account that the length of the name is contained in the string itself. Somehow the `.+` in the name group should be replaced by `.{4}`. I tried `{$1}`, `{${namlen}}` but that does not yield the result I expect (on rubular.com or regex.191)

Any ideas or further references?

Comment: You can't do that in plain regex, in Perl, you can use code blocks insertions in the pattern to achieve this.

Comment: I'm not a regex expert so maybe I don't know some regex tricks there  , but it seems pretty easy when doing it in multiple steps. Like: 1. Find `X<number>I`, 2. Use the `<number>` from step 1. and another regex to find the `name`, 3. etc...

Comment: Seems like iterative code solution (reading the string character by character) would be both optimal and easier to both write and understand than trying to come up with a regex solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask for is only possible in languages that allow code insertions in the regex pattern.

Here is a [Perl example](https://ideone.com/PAXNua):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $text = "X4IitemX6Nabc123";
if ($text =~ m/^X(?<namelen>[0-9]+)I(?<name>(??{".{".$^N."}"}))X(?<numlen>[0-9]+)N(?<num>.+)$/) {
    print $text . ": PASS!\n";
} else {
    print $text . ": FAIL!\n"
}
# -> X4IitemX6Nabc123: PASS!
```

In other languages, use a two-step approach:

1. Extract the number after `X`,
2. Build a regex dynamically using the result of the first step.

See a JavaScript example:

```js
const text = "X4IitemX6Nabc123";
const rx1 = /^X(\d+)/;
const m1 = rx1.exec(text)
if (m1) {
  const rx2 = new RegExp(`^X(?<namelen>\\d+)I(?<name>.{${m1[1]}})X(?<numlen>\\d+)N(?<num>.+)$`)
  if (rx2.test(text)) {
    console.log(text, '-> MATCH!')
  } else console.log(text, '-> FAIL!');
} else {
  console.log(text, '-> FAIL!')
}
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/5cxiwe):

```py
import re
text = "X4IitemX6Nabc123"
rx1 = r'^X(\d+)'
m1 = re.search(rx1, text)
if m1:
  rx2 = fr'^X(?P<namelen>\d+)I(?P<name>.{{{m1.group(1)}}})X(?P<numlen>\d+)N(?P<num>.+)$'
  if re.search(rx2, text):
    print(text, '-> MATCH!')
  else:
    print(text, '-> FAIL!')
else:
  print(text, '-> FAIL!')

# => X4IitemX6Nabc123 -> MATCH!
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I cannot change the code, so I have to change the barcode :-)